# Existing C++ *nix system library?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

There are several good cross-platform libraries, by which we usually mean something that wraps the commonalities of Windows and *nix.  Is there anything for developers that don't really care about Windows but want the benefits of C++ wrapping *nix system calls?

I am thinking of a library that reduces the tedium of struct setup, checking return codes and errno, throws appropriate (and actionable) exceptions, and generally reduces the system call boilerplate.

I accept that there are some standalone syscalls for which this might not make sense but there are plenty which could be naturally grouped e.g. stat/lstat/fstat, getpid/getppid/geteuid/etc.

Is there anything good out there?

Comment: You might get a good answer on here, but it could also pay to check http://www.trumphurst.com/cpplibs/cpplibs.php and then Google/ask for specific feedback on likely-sounding libraries....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) and [Boost Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) cover a lot of that ground. Threading is also included in C++0x.

Don't know of any for managing process information a la `getpid`, though. What other kinds of info and interfaces would be bundled into a `process` object?